# Trouble running specflow tests with VS2015 and resharper?

Tags: specflow

I'm using SpecFlow with Visual Studio 2013 without issue with Resharper 8.2. If I try running the tests in Visual Studio 2015 with Resharper 10 I get a "Not implemented" error if I right click a scenario and choose Run Unit Tests (worked in 2013 this way) and if I choose the Run SpecFlow Scenario option instead the project seems to build but the test never runs.

Has anyone else run into this? I tried uninstalling resharper, but it tells me no tests are found if I do that and "Run SpecFlow Scenarios" inside my feature file.

Comment: Which Unit Test provider are you using?

Comment: I was trying to use NUnit (as I was previously), but it doesn't show up under Tools > Options > SpecFlow > Test Runner Tool. It does show up in the app.config however. I installed the nuget packages for SpecFlow and the NUnit runners. I've also tried toggling the different other test runners listed there to see if anything does work (Auto, Resharper, VisualStudio2010MSTest, SpecRun, ReSharper5, VisualStudio2012), but had no luck. If I install the SpecRun nuget trial package that works, but I don't want to incur licensing fees when it worked with nunit before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a known issue with Resharper 10 (And some versions of 9) and Specflow (The bindings)

I spent many hours last week banging my head against a wall with it (Someone decided to upgrade to R# 10 and all hell breaks loose with testing)

After many hours of playing around I worked out that certain versions work with certain versions of specflow (Currently)..
Image of versions grid (Selenium to Resharper version combinations that work) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxh9G.png (Text as I cant post more than 2 links -_-)

This is hopefully a short term issue (For VS 2013/2015 anyways) as there is what looks like a fix in progress. [Here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/435) for these two versions of visual studio (Specflow wise). Those links have more info in them (Than my short explanation)

For anyone still using VS 2010 or 2012 whether the Specflow plugin will ever be updated for these versions I don't know... (That being that version 1.9.2 of specflow) for those versions of VS has not been updated since 2013... (Could be updated I don't know however keep that in mind...)

TL;DR

The issue is basically Resharper test hooks have been changed again by the looks of it in R# 9.2+ (In some way). Which is why SpecFlow is not playing ball any more with higher versions! (Basically a waiting on a updated version) which for VS 2010 and 2012 may never come :(

Comment: May be sooner than I thought
http://www.specflow.org/news/

Looks like things may be on the upgrade already (Going to give the pre release a try...)

Comment: Paired it with R# 9.1.3 like in your image and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: This is still a problem with R# Ultimate 2016.2.2, and Specflow 2015.1.2. My workaround is to avoid the Specflow context menu, and run the tests as straight unit tests instead:
Right-click on the project containing the tests, or, on the **.cs** file for an individual acceptance test (not the .feature file!), and you'll see **Run Unit Tests**. This seems to bypass Specflow, but the tests run fine, in a R# test session, so there's practically no difference to me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the only thing I had to change is the follwoing setting fdrom Auto to Resharper - and it worked:

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me with Specflow 1.9 and R# 2016.2.2

Comment: This didn't work for me either with Specflow 2015.1.2 and R# Ultimate 2016.2.2. I tried all the other settings, and the one that "worked" was **VisualStudio2012**, meaning that tests ran successfully, but (obviously) in the Visual Studio Test Explorer window, not R#... :-|

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS2015 / ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.2 and was able to run after installing SpecRun.Runner v1.5.2 from NuGet / restarting VS2015. (As a side note I also have the "SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2015" extension installed).